# How to compare functions?

Tags: r, function

Is there a way to compare whether two function objects are the same?

```
m <- mean
m == mean ## don't work

## this seems not to be the correct way:
functionBody(mean)==functionBody(m)
```

*EDIT*: Some more details. I have a function with two arguments (a matrix and a user-defined function which is applied columnwise, e.g. mean, median, ...). If the function is `mean` I want to use `colMean` instead (to save some running time).

```
foo <- function(m, fun) {
  #if (fun==mean) {
  #  return(colMeans(m));
  #} else {
    return(apply(m, 2, fun));
  #}
}
```

Comment: What is your definition of "equal functions"? If you mean *observably equivalent* then your question is undecidable!

Comment: You might find [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9473804/324364) question helpful.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You can use `identical`:

```
identical(m,mean)
```

Comment: Counter-example: m <- function (y, ...) { UseMethod("mean") } ;  m(c(1,2,3)) ; identical(mean, m) # [1] FALSE

Comment: @DWin: Obviously, this method checks only whether the two variables point to the same function, not whether the code used is the same. If the OP needed the latter, he/she wouldn't have written "this seems not to be the correct way" over the body check IMO...

Comment: @DWin: however, IMO equality for functions can be obtained only checking whether they refer to the same; otherwise, yes you can cope a couple of cases, but basically, as correctly pointed out in Basile's comment, the problem is undecidable...

Comment: I thought that function(x) (mean(x)} would be considered to be the "same" as function(y){mean(y)}. I assumed that a wizard (obviously not me) would come by and show us all how to use `substitute` using the formals(fn) as arguments on body(fn) to make that comparison. I do understand that this would not compare the equality of inputs and outputs, which would be Basile's more correct same-ness criterion.

Comment: @DWin: yep, probably something can be done for that case. But it doesn't change too much because a number (infinite) of other cases (e.g. `function(x){a=0;mean(x)+a}`) wouldn't be recognized.

Comment: @digEmAll @DWin : `identical` seems to be sufficient for my use case. The counter-example won't break my code. It will only slow down the calculation a little bit.

Answer (score 8):

I use `isTRUE(all.equal(function1,function2))`, but this suffers from similar drawbacks to the other methods.

Interestingly though, `all.equal` gives a nice summary of how the two operands differ (try `all.equal(function1,function2)`.

Answer (score 3):

You can convert the functions to strings,
and compare those strings.

```
equal_functions <- function(f,g)
  all( 
    capture.output(print(f)) ==
    capture.output(print(g))
  )
equal_functions(function(x) x, function(x) x) # TRUE
```

But functions that differ for non-essential reasons will be seen as different.

```
equal_functions(function(x) x, function(u) u) # FALSE
equal_functions(
  function(x) x, 
  function(x) 
    x
) # FALSE
```