# Comparing atomic and list types in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I get an error in the following code

```
> a <- dplyr::mutate
> a == dplyr::mutate
Error in a == dplyr::mutate : 
  comparison (1) is possible only for atomic and list types
```

How can I do this comparison then?
The use case is to put within a function with `a` as an argument. If `a` is the function `dplyr:::mutate`, i would want to do a certain execution.

Comment: Does this answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9638372/how-to-compare-functions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `identical` function:

```
> a <- dplyr::mutate
> identical(x = a, y = dplyr::mutate)
[1] TRUE
```