# R: Performance impact of blank lines and comments in long script

Tags: r, performance, comments

I'm wondering whether blank lines and comments have an impact on performance in R. I'm currently creating a large test battery of online experiments for academic research, and we expect a large number of participants, therefore I'm trying to keep things as efficient as possible. The various scripts for these tests tend to become quite long and conceptually tricky, hence I'm generously introducing blank lines and comments to increase their clarity. But now I'm wondering: do these have an impact on performance? If yes, is it substantial enough to warrant removing or limiting my use of blank lines and comments?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/15368168/

Comment: I knew it -- my search terms contained too many syllables I guess to return this one...

Comment: Heh, for what it's worth, I found it through google, which is usually better than SO's search bar.