# Are there any additional loads for interpreter if ";" set to the next line?

Tags: php, interpreter

I want to know how interpreter reads the instructions and end-symbol of it (;)

I tried to do some tests, but my hardware is not so sensitive to see the difference

For example, i have:

```php
$someObject->firstAction()->secondAction()->thirdAction();
```

How the interpreter will behave if i do this:

```php
$someObject
    ->firstAction()
    ->secondAction()
    ->thirdAction()
;
```

I want to find out if similar "beautiful" code formatting adversely affects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This format would work, yes, but it wouldn't fit the norms to work with other php programmers. https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-2/

But if you code it for yourself, then I don't see any issues.

AndyNope

Comment: So, for interpreter does not matter how code was styled

Comment: I have been taught, that it doesn't matter as long the interpreter understands your code. The interpreter works like a library and just call directly the mashine code or a bundle of binary codes that is named as that function.
**For Example:**
1 0000 B8140000  mov eax,0x14
1      00

Comment: I tested in a MVC framework and the performance was the same. Only the size of your file will increase. (1byte a space)

Comment: here another reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15368168/does-white-space-slow-down-processing 

I hope I could help you.